# Question for others as opposed to me

Tags: support, on-topic, self-answering

Can I ask a question if I know the answer but I think it may be useful for future viewers?

Essentially, I had a question that detailed research revealed the answer to but I could see other people having difficulty finding the answer.

Comment: It is worth noting that the entire SE system is built around generating Q&As that are useful, not just to the people asking them, but to people that come after.

Comment: *How much* detailed research?

Comment: @HeyICanChan more than was necessary it turns out, the answer was more obvious then it should have been, but I read through the entire Monster Manual and Volo's Guide checking for counter examples

Answer (score 11):

Absolutely, in fact its encouraged and I believe there is even a badge you can earn for doing it.

Comment: There is, but we should caution that this is only encouraged when the question is “real,” that is, a question you, or at least some reasonable person, could have had. The ideal form of a self-answered question is a question you had, and then found the answer to yourself. Self-answered Q&As are a great way to share your research and findings, but if it comes across as a semi-sneaky way to farm rep or promote a game you might get downvotes.

Comment: @KRyan ill keep that in mind and mention what sparked the question in my post